# List all functions of jquery select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to explore a jquery plugin.

```
var fb = new FormBuilder();
$(#fb).someMethod();
```

`console.log($(fb))` How can I list all the functions/methods that I can use here?

Comment: `$(#fb).someMethod();` isn't valid jQuery AFAIK

Comment: `console.log` the object and then you can see all the methods and properties of the object on the console. And good libraries have documentations!

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, here are the options you have:

1- Check the plugins' documentation. This is my prefer option because exploring the list of functions and methods DON"T necessarily describe the object's behaviour. However, documentation usually does

2- If the plugin is open source, then explore the internals by yourself

3- dump the object to the console using `console.log`. IMO, Google Chrome has one of the best (if not the best) developer tools integrated to the browser

4- Similar to the above you can add a breakpoint or a `debugger` statement to pause execution of javascript wherever you want and then explore the object in question

Below is a screenshot example of Chrome's Dev tools where I placed a breakpoint somewhere on this Stackoverflow page. You can see the `StackExchange`'s object definition

[image: Chrome Developer's Tool]